# How to get better prediction (lower Mean Absolute Error) with TF NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, linear-regression, tflearn

this is more strictly individual question, but I hope someone will help me here.

I am having this TF model which has to predict as accurately as possible a some continuous numbers. I am trying to get the result to be with MAE accuracy bellow 6400 but my closest MAE prediction was 79000.

I have 90 input features.
130000 rows of training data.
10000 rows of validation data.

My model:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 100
batch_size = 500
display_step = 1
# Network Parameters
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
n_hidden_1 = 180  # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 180  # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 180  # 3rd layer number of features
n_hidden_4 = 180  # 4th layer number of features
n_hidden_5 = 180  # 6th layer number of features
n_hidden_6 = 180  # 7th layer number of features
n_hidden_7 = 180  # 8th layer number of features
n_out = 1


init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=0.1, seed=None)
weights = {
    'h1': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h1', shape=[n_input, n_hidden_1], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h2': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h2', shape=[n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h3': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h3', shape=[n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h4': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h4', shape=[n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h5': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h5', shape=[n_hidden_4, n_hidden_5], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h6': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h6', shape=[n_hidden_5, n_hidden_6], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'h7': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h7', shape=[n_hidden_6, n_hidden_7], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
    'wout': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='wout', shape=[n_hidden_7, n_out], initializer=init), axis=[0])
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1, name='b1')),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1, name='b2')),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1, name='b3')),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1, name='b4')),
    'b5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_5], 0, 0.1, name='b5')),
    'b6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_6], 0, 0.1, name='b6')),
    'b7': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_7], 0, 0.1, name='b7')),
    'bout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_out], 0, 0.1, name='bout'))
}
# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
```

My cost function:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred) - y) / y)
```

My optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I am also preprocessing my test and validation data:

```
X_test_scale = preprocessing.scale(X_test)
```

I tried many variation, more layers more neurons, different optimizations, normalization, cost, learning rates, epochs, batch sizes function but I cannot get more that:

```
MAE: 79900.500000
MRE: 0.129946
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do it better?

Thank you!

Comment: Migrate to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or else DataScience.SE

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to point out a solution, but the one thing you haven't mentioned is regularization. Dropout or l2 regularization might help. Also, look at your learning curves and check if the model is overfitting.
With l2, for instance, you can do the following:

```
regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss(weights)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred) - y) / y + regularizer)
```

Most importantly, it seems that you don't use any activation function, as you're calling `multilayer_perceptron`. I think the best chance of improvement is to include a non-linear function in-between the layers, such as ReLU.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By adding a regularization you mean a regularization for the cost/loss function? About ReLu between the layers I already did it, but forgot to mention it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. For instance, there is a built-in function in tensorflow that you can use to calculate the l2 regularization and then just add the result to your loss function.

Comment: Thank you, it improved slightly, I would like to make more improvement though. I am new in TF so if you have any other ideas I can try them . I do not know if my cost function is really good, at the moment I am using:
`cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred) - y) / y + regularizer)` but would like to change it maybe. Also maybe I can try another optimizer although from what I read Adam is the best for my type of problem.


P.S. `regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h1']) + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['h2']) + .... + tf.nn.l2_loss(weights['wout'])`

Comment: If the regularization helped, you might try to increase its contribution to the loss function. ```cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.transpose(pred) - y) / y + k*regularizer)```. You can then adjust ```k``` to try to improve the results. It's another hyperparameter to fine-tune, but that is part of the fun :)
Also, have you tried dropout? It's the most effective type of regularization for neural-nets and there is a built-in function in TF for that as well: ```tf.nn.dropout```
Maybe you could also try to minimize the mean squared error, which is the standard loss function for regression.